# Setting a specific Icon to be shown on system tray via GPO

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, windows-10

I've been using at my office the application called SLACK and I'm having some problem with it, every time we get a new update the icon tends to hide and I want it to be shown on the system tray on all the computes in the office. Every update I have to manually go computer by computer so the application can be seen correctly.

Is there a way I can show a specific applications icon via GPO so the process goes more smoothly while they fix their bug.

Comment: This article might provide a solution for your problem: https://4sysops.com/archives/forcing-notification-area-icons-to-always-show-in-windows-7-or-windows-8/